# How do I get a uppercase or lowercase letter for Sixth and Seventh without getting other characters?

Tags: java

How do I get a uppercase or lowercase letter for Sixth and Seventh without getting other characters? (This question is for very beginners so I can't use if command or anything advanced)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomPasswordGenerator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        
        int First = generator.nextInt(26)+97;
        int Second = generator.nextInt(26)+97;
        int Third = generator.nextInt(10);
        int Fourth = generator.nextInt(26)+65;
        int Fifth = generator.nextInt(26)+65;
        int Sixth = generator.nextInt(58)+65;
        int Seventh = generator.nextInt(58)+65;

        System.out.print((char) First);
        System.out.print((char) Second);
        System.out.print((char) Third);
        System.out.print((char) Fourth);
        System.out.print((char) Fifth);
        System.out.print((char) Sixth);
        System.out.println((char) Seventh);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome! You didn't describe how current behavior of your code differs from what you're trying to achieve. To update the question, use the *edit* button, or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73911745/edit). Also, please get familiar with the guide-lines on how to ask questions [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

the other character are from 91 to 96

you can do this condition for Sixth or Seven

```
int Sixth = generator.nextInt(58)+65;
Sixth = ( Sixth < 97 && Sixth > 90 ) ? 97 : Sixth
```